# Web API - Inject dependency at ServiceContainer using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using `ExceptionLogger` to handle all the global exception. My inheriting class requires dependencies to be injected for `Nlog` to invoke.

```
public class NLogExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;

    public NLogExceptionLogger(ILoggingService<NLogExceptionLogger> loggingService)
    {
        _loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        _loggingService.FirstLevelServiceLog(context.Exception.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

LoggingService Class:

```
public class LoggingService<T> : ILoggingService<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingService()
    {
        string currentClassName = typeof(T).Name;
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(currentClassName);
    }

    public void FirstLevelServiceLog(string log)
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, log);
    }
}
```

My Unity Code:

```
public static UnityContainer RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType(typeof(ILoggingService<>), typeof(LoggingService<>))
}
```

I am registering `ExceptionLogger` globally by doing: (On this line i am getting an error)

```
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), typeof(NLogExceptionLogger));
//Register Dependency Container
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.RegisterComponents());
```

I am getting following error at runtime:

> **System.ArgumentException: 'The type RuntimeType must derive from IExceptionLogger.'**

My assumption is i am not properly registering the dependency for `NLogExceptionLogger`.

Any idea on how to resolve dependency while registering the service?

Comment: Did you properly set up the dependency resolver? And also When adding service you add the instance. `config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), {instance here});`

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes, I have edited the question with resolver code.

Comment: Right I would suggest you set that before adding the service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding service to `ServicesContainer` you add the type with the service instance.

Assuming dependency resolver has already been setup, that can be used to resolve the instance if it has dependencies.

```
var logger = config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(NLogExceptionLogger));
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), logger);
```

There is also a difference between exceptions loggers and exception handlers.

I suggest reviewing the following reference link to determine which one is appropriate for your needs.

Reference [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)